# How to switch user given a UID?

Tags: linux, sudo, user-accounts, su

I only know the UID of a user, is it possible to switch user using UID in linux distribution like we do using username like `su -u someuser`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up the username with the `id` command, e.g.:

```
id -un 1003
```

Then put it together with command substitution:

```
su - $(id -un 1003)
```

Comment: What if the user ID 1003 has no name?

Answer (score 11):

If you have `sudo` installed, you can specify a user by UID. The user doesn't even need to exist in `/etc/passwd`:

```
# sudo -u \#1234 id
uid=1234 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Interesting observation: if you have sufficient 'sudo' permissions, this method can be used to act as a user who has been disabled a la https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7690/how-do-i-completely-disable-an-account